# как сделать обработчик слов aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

я могу сделать обработчик команд с помощью

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['тест'])
```

но он срабатывает только при вводе "/тест". как мне сделать чтобы он срабатывал при вводе "тест"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте фильтр [Text](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/filters.html#text):

```
@dp.message_handler(filters.Text(equals='тест'))
```